# How to print MACRON/Unicode in Windows Console

Tags: c++, unicode, character-encoding, console-application, codeblocks

So currently I'm working with Unicode a lot lately.
I've seen others facing the same issue but so far no answer solved my issue.

The objective is at the moment is to be able to print: `¯` in my Windows Console Window.
The character is called "MACRON" and its Unicode number is U+00AF.

At first I simple wrote: `cout << "some irrelevant text lorem ipsum etc... \u00AF" << endl;`

But this ended up backfiring at me with the windows console window displaying a *weird indescribable ugly (no offence)* looking T.

**I've also tried to use wcout** `wcout << L"some more irrelevant text lorem ipsum etc... \u00AF" << endl;`
 but the outcome is the same.

Any thoughts as to why my source code/console window is unable to print the MACRON character?

A fix for this character is good but overall I'll encounter weirder and weirder Unicode character so I may need a broader applicable solution **without downloading/changing anything outside of the source code.**

Programming with C++ in Code::Blocks 17.12 IDE

Comment: The traditional Windows console is not good at Unicode. It probably shows the extended ASCII and the characters from the currently selected codepage well though. And `0x00AF` is in the range of extended ASCII so commonly used on Windows. What is your locale settings? What codepage is used?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with locale settings? Local settings of Windows? Codeblocks? C++?. You mean my current charset right? UTF-9 though I feel like you mean the windows char-list but I can't tell with little details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_setmode(..., _O_U16TEXT);`

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

...

_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
std::wcout << L"\u00AF\n";
```

Just make sure to read the caveats on the docs page to make sure you're happy with the trade-offs of using it (for example plain `printf` will no longer work in that mode):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=vs-2017

Comment: thanks. I'm getting come weird errors: '_fileno' was not declared in this scope". Am I missing something?

Comment: @StellarEquilibrium Add  `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: the mode (u16text..) was no declared as well so I changed that to ", 0x00020000" and the programm starts though now the console is empty and I read somewhere that you need to change the font to lucidia console which obv. is not going to happen as described in the question

Comment: Sorry, it works out of the box for me (windows10, vs2017). Not sure what is different for you.

Comment: Also that Lucinda advice looks... old. I'd be very surprised if it still applied to a more modern OS. No actual knowledge tho.